# Foreshadow vs Adumbrate

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, synonyms, discourse-markers

> - The good news was **foreshadowed** by several disturbing events.
> - The good news was **adumbrated** by several disturbing events.

I am trying to see which word is better to use. Is there a (subtle) distinction between the two words? I know the word "adumbrated" is more formal as opposed to using the word "foreshadowed", but *that* word sounds better, in my opinion; or at least, it sounds better in the particular sentence as shown in the sandbox.

Comment: If your goal is to confuse your reader, use "adumbrated".

Comment: You're asking a number of interesting but opinion-based questions. Your sample sentence doesn't work well with either of the two words (why would something good anticipate something disturbing?). Adumbrate means a number of things, but where it overlaps with foreshadow, the former is weaker (only a hint). And really, assessing a neologism is difficult (and usually makes for a poor question here).

Comment: I am truly vestibulated by your adulatorial selection of incondefoundable words. We must meet immediately and counterdifibulate about a new dictionary.

Comment: @NigelJ -- No, no, no!  A new cyclopedia of onomastics!

Comment: I would expect the foreshadowing and foreshadowed events to tend in the same direction, not like a disturbing event and good news.

Comment: Is there some connection between the top part of your question and the bottom part?

Comment: @aparente001 Nah, not really ;)

Comment: @NigelJ The best lexicological comment ever xD

Comment: @Mitch Sorry about the poor sample sentence... I was kind of using an ironic sentence to precisely grasp the meaning of the two words. But most of all, apologies for the poor question.

Comment: @user477343 - Since the two parts are unrelated, and since separate questions have to be posted as separate questions, I took out the second part.  You can post it as a separate question if you wish.  I didn't do that for you because I didn't understand it well enough. // Do you know how to edit a question?  You can improve it after you get feedback.  You're not stuck with whatever you initially typed.

Comment: @aparente001 yeah, I believe there is a "rollback" feature or something. I am aware of how to edit a question nonetheless, and I appreciate your edit. In my future questions, my made up words will just go in a comment, so thanks for your edit actually :P

Comment: @user477343 - Yes, you're on the right track.  If someone edits your question and you're not happy with the changes, then you click where it says "edited 5 hours ago" or whatever, and choose the older version -- that's the rollback.  But you can edit your question yourself, and for that, you click "edit" (between "share" on the left, and "close" and "flag" on the right).  That whole area is more or less on the left.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for letting me know! I won't edit the question, though, because I think it's alright :)

Answer (score 1):

The most important difference between the two words is that ***foreshadowed*** is a commonly used word, particularly in literature and drama, while ***adumbrated*** is so rarely used that I do not recall having heard of it before and I certainly did not know what it meant when I read this question. (And I have what is considered an excellent vocabulary.) Google's [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foreshadowed%2Cadumbrated&year_start=1970&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforeshadowed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadumbrated%3B%2Cc0) shows *foreshadowed* is used about 5 times as often as *adumbrated*.

Certain literary magazines prefer to use obscure words to expose them to their readers, thereby improving their reader's vocabularies. Those magazines might choose to use *adumbrated*. People who want to be understood would use *foreshadowed*.